# Me falta agregar un Metodo en Java

Tags: java, bluej

Me falta un código de abajo que nose como podría realizarlo, al final de todo el código que puse como quisiera que quedara pero nose por donde comenzar para crear ese método teniendo los datos que he creado
alguien podría orientarme en como poder crear dicho código al final?
Al ingresar una moneda se debe verificar que sea la moneda correcta 10, 50, 100 o 500, en el caso que no corresponda deberá entregar un mensaje de “Moneda inválida”, en el caso que corresponda la moneda se deberá determinar a cual parte del contenedor de monedas se agregará y contabilizará la moneda indicando “Moneda ingresada”.

````
{
    //Contenedor de vuelto
    private int cantM10;
    private int cantM50;
    private int cantM100;
    private int cantM500;
    //Contenedor de monedas entrantes
    private int cantCajaM10;
    private int cantCajaM50;
    private int cantCajaM100;
    private int cantCajaM500;
    
    public Caja(int cantM10, int cantM50, int cantM100, int cantM500){
       this.cantM10 = 0;
       this.cantM50 = 0;
       this.cantM100 = 0;
       this.cantM500 = 0;
       this.cantCajaM10 = 0;
       this.cantCajaM50 = 0;
       this.cantCajaM100 = 0;
       this.cantCajaM500 = 0;
       
    }
    
    //Metodo para verificar si la moneda es valida o no
    private boolean verificarMoneda(int moneda){
        if(moneda==10){
            return true;
        }
        if(moneda==50){
            return true;
        }
        if(moneda==100){
            return true;
        }
        if(moneda==500){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    //Metodo get para contenedor de vuelto
    public int getCantM10(){
        return cantM10;
    }
    public int getCantM50(){
        return cantM50;
    }
    public int getCantM100(){
        return cantM100;
    }
    public int getCantM500(){
        return cantM500;
    }
    public int getCantCajaM10(){
        return cantCajaM10;
    }
    public int getCantCajaM50(){
        return cantCajaM50;
    }
    public int getCantCajaM100(){
        return cantCajaM100;
    }
    public int getCantCajaM500(){
        return cantCajaM500;
    }
    
    /*Metodo que permita ingresar moneda, verificando que la moneda sea valida e ingresando la moneda
     * al contenedor de monedas, si la moneda no es valida, que salga un mensaje diciendo que no lo es
     */
    
    public String ingresarMoneda(int moneda){
        
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo al parecer te toco una tarea similar a la mía pero bueno:
Estoy aprendiendo el arte de la programacion y soy estudiante de primer año.
busque y cree el código y dentro de las muchas posibilidades llegue a esto.
espero te funcione Saludos.

```java
public String ingresarMoneda(int moneda){
    string = "";
    if (moneda == 10) {
        string = "moneda valida.";
    } else if (moneda == 50) {
        string = "moneda valida.";
    } else if (moneda == 100) {
        string = "moneda valida.";
    } else if (moneda == 500) {
        string = "moneda valida.";
    } else {
        string = "moneda invalida.";
    }
    return string;
}
```

Comment: Con un *or* podrías simplificar el código.